# How to verify PGP detached signature using Bouncycastle

Tags: java, kotlin, cryptography, bouncycastle

I want to parse and verify an OpenPGP detached signature using Bouncycastle. The signature would be something like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: fast-openpgp

wsBcBAABCAAQBQJfRm9jCRDzeoZuOgUYnQAAVkoIAEReZ6Pp3SimYKbH+JHzwW8q
LiWeQIPNatFwDQHgD4ipT9aXMaObnXXl83KUQ5lPx8Bw77BxParpUbtCRNTrWoU5
XZ1ikfqzmeVEJrk4YsNKDiBpvjbyF86F8KSkXhwdLWSm1e6yemnXKcTHg2L13AiS
6TIqXXbcRmFF7RTO4DQrjira2YYlW8eHPIcCmOq0YjR4Qpz+R/+3BlfV2TAcL/sd
SeKAczgvdP6CS6be1rPA0nlgw9T853BpgqplQVM30pUhVlni7ga1YRzENm6Qic5A
uEbmPyunim2WHytPuLQq+BQvAq+Wrr2kiM7DhyvYFihDNdFWW67Y+fSlgPxOi/8=
=QKpc
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

And here is how I try to create CMSSignedData in Kotlin:

```
fun verifyDetached(signatureString: String, dataString: String): Boolean {
    val dataBytes = dataString.toByteArray()
    val signatureBytes = signatureString.toByteArray()
    val processableDataBytes = CMSProcessableByteArray(dataBytes)
    val ci = ContentInfo.getInstance(ASN1Sequence.fromByteArray(signatureBytes))
    val cms = CMSSignedData(processableDataBytes, ci)
    ...
}
```

When I pass the whole signature block into the function (including -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----) I get `java.io.IOException: unknown tag 13 encountered`.

When I remove signature wrappers and just pass in the signature content into the function I get `java.io.IOException: Extra data detected in stream at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray`.

When I directly pass `signatureBytes` to CMSSignedData constructor I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLApplicationSpecific`.

How should I verify this kind of signature using Bouncycastle?

Comment: **CMS is completely and totally different from and not related to PGP**. For PGP use the BouncyCastle implementation of PGP in bcpg, NOT the implementation of CMS in bcpkix. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170230/verification-of-pgp-signature-using-bouncycastle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57574714/how-to-sign-and-verify-the-file-in-java

Comment: Oh Thanks! it seems I confused APIs, I thought CMS API was supposed to handle both detached signatures for PGP and certificates context. thanks for your hint and links. Please post your answer so I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Done. _Both_ CMS and PGP have detached signatures, but they are unrelated. CMS has either embedded or detached signatures, and the CMS implementation handles both. PGP has either embedded or detached signatures, plus in the armored format 'clearsigned' messages which contain both the data plus a signature in detached format (but since it's with the data not so truly detached), and the PGP implementation handles these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMS is completely and totally different from and not related to PGP. For PGP use the BouncyCastle implementation of PGP in bcpg, NOT the implementation of CMS in bcpkix. See e.g. [Verification of PGP signature using BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170230/verification-of-pgp-signature-using-bouncycastle) and [How to sign and verify the file in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57574714/how-to-sign-and-verify-the-file-in-java) .